# How to clone a folder(not only its contents) into another folder using cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, xcopy

While using the "xcopy" feature(and also "/e"), I could copy the contents of Folder_A to Folder_B, but the name "Folder_A" would not be present(except only the files and sub directories inside "Folder_A"), how do I do this?

E.g;

Folder_A(has 3 files inside)

Folder_B

---

I.e;

In the GUI I could right click on Folder_A and click copy, then right click on Folder_B and click paste, finally resulting in a clone of the Folder_A inside Folder_B. That is what I want to do on the command line!

Comment: Try using copy and specify full directory.

Comment: What about providing the command line you used (by [edit]ing the question), so we might be able to tell you what you did wrong... *Hint:* don't specify `Folder_B` as the target, try `Folder_B\Folder_A` instead...

Comment: This is what I tried; xcopy Folder_A Folder_B /e

Comment: I think I figured it out, thanks for the help, what I actually needed to do was the put "/Folder_A" after the destination link(that actually created Folder_A inside Folder_B)(instead of only copying the inner files of Folder_A to Folder_B). The code looks like; xcopy Folder_A Folder_B\Folder_A /e

Comment: That code above would output(For which I would type "D" and press enter);Does Folder_B\Folder_A specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?

Comment: Use this code: xcopy Folder_A Folder_B\Folder_A\ /e  (The '\' at the end of the destination supresses the question. The destination path is taken as a directory, and it is created if it does not exist already.)

Answer (score 0):

copy Folder_A Folder_B *.*
This will copy all the contents of Folder_A to Folder_B and leaves contents of Folder_a as it is.
[image: Sample Output]

Comment: I think I figured it out, thanks for the help, what I actually needed to do was the put "/Folder_A" after the destination link(that actually created Folder_A inside Folder_B)(instead of only copying the inner files of Folder_A to Folder_B). The code looks like; xcopy Folder_A Folder_B\Folder_A /e

Comment: That code above would output(For which I would type "D" and press enter);Does Folder_B\Folder_A specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?

Comment: copy Folder_A Folder_B : This actually copies all the contents (files and sub folders) of Folder_A) inside Folder_B.

Comment: I will add sample output